# Pulling a specific value from a key with dic

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to pull a particular value(s) from key 'ip', in this example its 192.168.200.200, but in some cases it will be different and there can be more than be more than one. I am new to python, can someone help me pull out the values?

```
# import functions
from cisco_xe_api import *

# define variables
device_config = api_get_conf()

# Rule SV-105995r2_rule: The Cisco router must be configured to implement message
# authentication for all control plane protocols.
def sv105995r2rule_ospf():
    #device_config = api_get_conf()
    routing_protocol = device_config['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native']['router']
    ospf_networks = device_config['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native']['router']['Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf']['ospf']
    protocol_intf = device_config['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native']['interface']
    if 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf' in routing_protocol.keys():
       print('\nOSPF is configured on this device. Checking for MD5 authentication.'
       print(ospf_networks.items())
```

Here is the output from the print statement:

```
OSPF is configured on this device. Checking for MD5 authentication.
dict_items([('process-id', [{'id': 100, 'area': [{'area-id': 0, 'authentication': {'message-digest': [None]}}], 'network': [{'ip': '192.168.200.200', 'wildcard': '0.0.0.0', 'area': 0}]}])])
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you want to store the ips values in case there are few of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure is dict → list → dict → list → dict, so in your example, you can get the IP like this:

```
ospf_networks['process-id'][0]['network'][0]['ip']
```

I don't know anything about the API you're using, but assuming any of the lists could have multiple items, printing all the IPs would look like this:

```
for d0 in ospf_networks['process-id']:
    for d1 in d0['network']:
        print(d1['ip'])
```

Answer (score 1):

For the example you provided, the code to get ip would be:

```
ospf_networks['process_id'][0]['network'][0]['ip']
```

It goes like this:

- That is we get a value key 'process_id'.
- This value is a list.
- In this example there is only a single element in this list.
- We get that element and it is a dict.
- This dict has a the following keys: 'id', 'area', 'network'.
- We get the value by key 'network'.
- The values is yet another list with a single element.
- It's yet another dict with keys 'ip', 'wildcard' and 'area'.
- We get the value by 'ip' key.

Now to get multiple ip addresses ospf_networks dict it would entirely depend on where they would fit in the structure.

Comment: The value at `'network'` is another list, so you'll need to add another indexing there: `...['network'][0]['ip']`

Comment: if you're not aware, you can [edit] your answer. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour].